# How do I install Boost.signals2 into my project?

Tags: c++, boost

I'm having trouble succesfully including Boost.signals2 in my project so i can have an event-like system for button presses with my OpenGL window. 
I downloaded boost.signals2 from its github page and took the contents of the Include folder, and put it into my own Include folder that i have included in my project (this is so i can just add stuff i need as i go and have something i can share across projects).

Problem is, when i build my project after including Boost.signals2, and having the line `#Include <boost/signals2/signal.hpp>` i am presented with a bunch of errors from all the Boost.signals2 headers, all of which are `cannot open source file "boost/config.hpp": No such file or directory` or some other `boost/{x}.hpp`. I'm at a total loss as to where i'm going wrong. As far as i understand, i do not have to build the Boost.signals2 library as it is header only, but maybe i am wrong?
How can install Boost.signals2?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to add the include path for the complete boost libraries to your compile flags.

If you extracted the tarball in directory XYZ, the include path would just be that (so `-I XYZ` or `-isystem XYZ`).

Signals2 in particular is header only, so it doesn't need to be built and/or linked.

Comment: So essentially i need the entire boost library and can't only have Signals2 alone?

Comment: It's the convenient thing to do. Technically, there's isn't any effective difference anyways, since it's all header-only. If you really want to try and conserve on-disk footprint you **could** look at the BCP tool, but in practice I've found the size benefits to be marginal.

Comment: Thanks, i downloaded the whole library and compiled it, and added all of the boost headers to my include folder, and the built library folders to my libraries folder and now it compiles without a hitch. I just had to add ``_SCL_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS to Project->Properties->C/C++->Preprocessor->Preprocessor Definitions``.
Do i have to add Additional Dependencies to the Input of the Linker for the specific non-header-only portions of boost i may ever use (like..i dunno.. signals.lib) or is that unneccessay?

Comment: Oh. You never mentioned you were using MSVC (I just looked at the way you spelled the include paths). Not that it makes a lot of difference. You shouldn't have had to compile it, like I said: Signals2 is header-only. Signals.lib is for the "old" library (not Signals2) so you donot need it.

Comment: You might add the library-path since you compiled them anyways (it'll be in stage/lib or so). That way when you do use a library that is not header-only, [AutoLinking](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_67_0/more/getting_started/windows.html#auto-linking) will kick will add the required linker inputs using #pragma directives for MSVC